# Adjective that describes an event happening in the US can impact Europe?

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for an adjective to describe that an event occurring in the United States can have impact on the European market. The first word coming up to my mind is "transcontinental" and the sentence I write is

> In building the model, we should also take into account the **transcontinental** effect of bankruptcy of the US banks.

However, I don't find "transcontinental" to be an ideal choice. According to the first search result returned by google, transcontinental means "*(especially of a railway line) crossing a continent*.", so it seems that it is more appropriate to use the word to describe a physical entity.

So can anyone recommend a more suitable word? Or maybe transcontinental is a good choice and I have some misunderstanding? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: _Intercontinental_ might work for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Transcontinental would apply to an effect or influence by one side of a continent on the other, not to the effect of one continent on another. What separates America and Europe is an ocean. In business and cultural contexts, one frequently sees discussion of **transatlantic** effects:

> Barack Obama's brave attempt to reform the U.S. healthcare system had
>   an unexpected transatlantic effect
>
> Amplifying this transatlantic effect for purchasers of the 1893 volume
>   in which the poem appeared were its illustrations
>
> Queen Alexandra's letter did have a positive, if transatlantic,
>   effect. The president of the U. S. Audobon Society sent a copy to
>   President Theodore Roosevelt

Comment: It's a bit of an oddity, this one. As you say, ***transcontinental*** is normally understood to mean ***continent-wide*** (but contained within a *single* continent, not ***intercontinental***, spanning multiple continents), whereas ***transnational*** normally means ***multinational***, not ***nationwide***.

Comment: This word is really confusing, especially with the fixed term expression "transcontinental flight" where they claim that "it is a non-stop passenger flight from one side of a continent to the other."

Here's more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcontinental_flight